# Best way to remove duplicate sentences from an array of sentences based on their characters, whitespaces inconsequential

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

Let say we have an array like this

```
const array = ['bic ycle drive', 'bici ycl frei', 'bicyc le dri ve', 'manace', 'bicycle drive', 'bicycle drive']
```

I want it to return `['bic ycle drive', 'bici ycl frei', 'manace']` because `bic ycle drive, bicyc le dri ve, bicycle drive, bicycle drive` are the same sentence with white space in different places.

**Summary: Just return unique values, white space is not important.**

Ps: We can pick any of the duplicates.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't return directly the word without space?

Comment: _"Best way to..."_ asks for an opinion which is off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ES6 it's easy to create arrays of unique values using a Set, but in this case you need to transform the strings (remove spaces) to find the duplicates, but still preserve the original strings, so you can return them.  You can do this by creating a Map with the "string without space" as the key, and the original string as the value. Since Map's keys are unique.

Create a Map by using `Array.map()` to generate an array of `[string without spaces, string]`. Then convert the `Map.values()` iterator back to an array. This will return the last item in each series of duplicates.

```js
const array = ['bic ycle drive', 'bici ycl frei', 'bicyc le dri ve', 'manace', 'bicycle drive', 'bicycle drive']

const result = [...new Map(
  array.map(str => [str.replace(/\s+/g, ''), str])
).values()]

console.log(result)
```

If you want the first item in a series of duplicates, you can use `Array.reduce()` to create the Map, and only assign keys if they don't alreay exist:

```js
const array = ['bic ycle drive', 'bici ycl frei', 'bicyc le dri ve', 'manace', 'bicycle drive', 'bicycle drive']

const result = [...array.reduce((acc, str) => {
  const key = str.replace(/\s+/g, '')
  
  return acc.has(key) ? acc : acc.set(key, str)
}, new Map()).values()]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: it is very clever

Comment: This is really cool. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)